# VMPlayer cut-n-paste issue after VmTools

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, vmware-player, cut-and-paste

Using VMPlayer 4.06 on Ubuntu 14.04 on Win7.
I just installed the open-vm-tools-dkms (aptget) and the [patches](https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.gi) . This was done to solve the host/VM file sharing problem. Now a huge new problem has got created. **I can't cut-n-paste between my host and VM - this used to work perfectly earlier.**

How do I fix this.

If I have to un-install/redo how do I do?